# Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this hierarchy in a compose file,

```
Column {
    // Views
        Card{
            Column {
             // views
                // HERE I HAVE DYNAMIC LIST
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to solve it like this

```
LazyColumn {
    // Views
    item {
        Card{
            Column {
             // views
                items {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also like this:

```
Column {
    // Views
        Card{
            LazyColumn {
             // views
                items {
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and this

```
LazyColumn {
    // Views
        Card{
            LazyColumn {
             // views
                items {
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Nothing works, I need to add the dynamic list inside the column that is inside the card item, which is inside another column, any ideas about that?

Comment: You can't place multiple lazy column items inside one view, but you can make it look like this: draw top corner radius+shadow for the first item and bottom corner+shadow for the last one

Comment: you shouldn't use nesting components scrollable in the same direction